# Why does Oracle's download page suggest older Java version for download

Tags: java, download

The currently latest JRE version offered by Oracle is Java 1.8. If I visit Oracle's Java download page they provide the latest Java 1.7 as download:

http://www.java.com/download/

What's the reason for this behavior? In order to download Java 1.8 I need to visit the download section for "Java for developers". But if a non-developer tries to update or install the latest Java he/she clicks on "Java for your computer" and finds Java 1.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Why is Java 8 not available on java.com?**
>
> Java 8 is the latest release for Java that contains new features, enhancements and bug fixes to improve efficiency to develop and run Java programs.
>
> The new release of Java is first made available to developers to ensure no major problems are found before we make it available on the java.com website for end users to download. If you are interested in trying Java 8 it can be downloaded from Oracle.com.

Source: http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java8.xml

Comment: When will they decide to release Java 8 for the public?

Comment: They're very conservative with java.com updates, according to the [Chief Architect of the Java Platform Group's blog](http://mreinhold.org/blog/jdk8-ga#comment-1290525410). Presumably in a few months but it doesn't look like the date is set in stone yet.